# Using IsNull() in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query:

```
SELECT
    sc.ContactID
    , c.Price
    , p.ParkID
    FROM
        tblc c
        JOIN tblsc ON c.ID= sc.ID
        LEFT JOIN tblp p ON sc.ID= p.ID
    WHERE
        (stuff = stuff)
        AND (stuff = stuff)
```

Returns this:

```
ContactID    LeadSalePrice     ParkID
-------------------------------------
    1           50             NULL
    2           60              22
```

Now, I am trying to set up another `AND` clause for `ParkID`.  But, I only want to execute this `AND` on rows where `ParkID` IS NOT NULL.  So, if on rows where `ParkID` IS NULL, we want to always keep those rows.  On rows where ParkID IS NOT NULL, we only want to keep those rows if `ParkID` matches the parameter.

If @ParkID = 22, then return both rows.

If @ParkID <> 22, then only return the top row.

If @ParkID = NULL, then return both rows.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    sc.ContactID
    , c.Price
    , p.ParkID
FROM
    tblc c
    JOIN tblsc ON c.ID= sc.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblp p ON sc.ID= p.ID
    WHERE 
        (stuff = stuff)
        AND (stuff = stuff)
        AND p.ParkID = 
            CASE WHEN p.ParkID IS NULL THEN 
                NULL
           ELSE
                @ParkID
            END
```

This doesn't work because the proper way to compare with null is not:

```
= NULL
```

It's

```
IS NULL
```

For the same reason (I assume), this doesn't work either:

```
AND p.ParkID = Isnull(p.ParkID, @ParkID)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply check if `p.ParkID` is `NULL` *or* it matches `@ParkID`:

```
WHERE p.ParkID IS NULL
   OR p.ParkID = @ParkID
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll test this

Answer (score 1):

More compact:

```
WHERE p.ParkID IN ('', NULL)
```